# determining original cause of error

Tags: c, error-handling

Is there some well known pattern/practice for nested error handling in C, something like nested exceptions in Java?

With the usual "just return error code/success" error details may be lost before a program can determine it should log/report error.

Imagine a code similar to this:

```
err B()
{
  if (read(a/b/c/U.user) != OK) {
    return read_error; //which would be eaccess or we could return even e_cannot_read_user
  }

  if (is_empty(read_user.name)) {
    // we could tell exactly what is missing here
    return einval;
  }
  ...
}

err A()
{
  if (B() != OK) {
    if (cannot_handle_B_failing()) {
      return e_could_not_do_b;
    }
  }
  ...
}

main()
{
  ...
  if (A() != OK) && (no_alternative_solution()) {
    report error_returned_by_A;
    wait_for_more_user_input();
  }
}
```

Has anyone successfully tried some kind of nested error codes/messages in C for situations like that? Something that could report (in main) the fact that user name was missing or that file F can not be read due to invalid permissions.

Is there a library to support something like this?

Comment: One of the approaches I have seen - you report error using 32-bit int - but split it in ranges, low 16 bits are error code - set by lower layer functions, next 8 bits are reserved for middle-layer function and highest 8 bits are reserved for usage by top layer functions. Error received from B is then |= in the A with additional info

Comment: The short answer is no. C is the blank slate of programming languages. There are few broadly used idioms to implement what in bigger languages are standard features: containers, exceptions, generics, etc. (The diversity of answers already given is some kind of proof.) In the Java exception sub-system you receive a linked list of causes. In C you can certainly write this yourself: return a pointer to chain of cause structs instead of an integer error code. If you want exception-like behavior, you can cobble that up without too much trouble using `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

Comment: I know that C is "invent your own wheel" of languages. And certainly you can write "cause list" yourself, but you must also clean up any dynamically allocated trace elements when handling errors, which is of course doable (by for example keeping some internal allocator and reuse "causes" or clean them up when new error is "created"). It is non-trivial enough to wonder if there is a library that solves this better than a solution written in few hours...

Comment: Thanks to all responders for input. Considering the answers the conslusion would be that there is not clear best way to handle errors and one needs to decide case by case.

Comment: @dbrank0, after coding C on and off for 20 years and having this problem (I am not very smart, the first years I don't think I even saw the problem) I have come into some kind of equilibrium in my projects, for this "determine failure reason": never good, never awful. What I mean is I look at it from case to case like you said, and arrive at some workable way, that never fits completely but always is *"OK, that looked kind of awkward in the fringes but it will do fair enough"*. Maybe someone will find a great way to do this. Or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at [Apple's error handling guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806). It was designed for Objective-C and the main class there is `NSError`. They are using a `userInfo` dictionary (map) for holding detailed info about the error, and they have predefined `NSUnderlyingErrorKey` constant for holding underlying `NSError` object in that dictionary if needed.

So you can declare your own error `struct` for your code and implement similar solution.

e.g.

```
typedef struct {
  int code;
  struct Error *underlyingError;
  char domain[0];
} Error;
```

You can then use `domain` field to categorize errors (by libs, files or functions as you want); `code` field to determine error itself and optional `underlyingError` field to find out what underlying error caused the error you received.

Comment: Thanks. Good source. Although bookkeeping Error struct (copy, destruct) in C sucks.

Comment: Otherwise you will need either to declare a constant for each error combination (>70% of your sources will become pure error handling code) or to store your errors as binary masks in one variable here you will have some flexibility as mentioned earlier. But anyway you will be limited in depth of nested functions (i.e. if you have 20 nested function calls you can't pass the error from the deepest function to caller).

Answer (score 3):

Each function may have its own independent, documented, and isolated set of errors. Like each function from the libc have their own documented set of possible return values and ERRNO codes.

The "root cause" is only an implementation detail, you just have to know "why" it failed.

In other words, A's documentation should not explain B, should not tell it uses B, nor tell about B's errors codes, it can have its own, locally meaningful, error codes.

Also while trying alternatives, you'll have to keep the origin failure codes (locally), so if the alternatives also fail you'll still be able to know what caused you to try them in the first place.

```
err B()
{
  if (read(a/b/c/U.user) != OK) {
    return read_error; //which would be eaccess or we could return even e_cannot_read_user
  }

  if (is_empty(read_user.name)) {
    // we could tell exactly what is missing here
    return einval;
  }
  ...
}

err A()
{
  if ((b_result = B()) != OK) {
    // Here we understand b_result as we know B,
    // but outside of we will no longer understand it.
    // It means that we have to map B errors
    // to semantically meaningful A errors.
    if (cannot_handle_B_failing()) {
      if (b_result == …)
          return e_could_not_do_b_due_to_…;
      else if (b_result == …)
          return e_could_not_do_b_due_to_…;
      else
          return e_could_not_do_b_dont_know_why;

    }
  }
  ...
}

main()
{
  ...
  if ((a_result = A()) != OK) && (no_alternative_solution()) {
    // Here, if A change its implementation by no longer calling B
    // we don't care, it'll still work.
    report a_result;
    wait_for_more_user_input();
  }
}
```

It's costly to map B's errors to A's errors, but there's a profit: when B will change its implementation, it won't break all A's call sites.

This semantical mapping may look useless at first ("I'll map a "permission denied" to a "permission denied"...) but has to be adapted to the current level of abstraction, typically from a "cannot open file" to an "cannot open configuration", like:

```
err synchronize(source, dest, conf) {
    conf_file = open(conf);
    if (conf == -1)
    {
       if (errno == EACCESS)
           return cannot_acces_config;
       else
           return unexpected_error_opening_config_file;
    }
    if (parse(config_file, &config_struct) == -1)
        return cannot_parse_config;
    source_file = open(source);
    if (source_file == -1)
    {
       if (errno == EACCESS)
           return cannot_open_source_file;
       else
           return unexpected_error_opening_source_file;
    }
    dest_file = open(dest);
    if (dest == -1)
    {
       if (errno == EACCESS)
           return cannot_open_dest_file;
       else
           return unexpected_error_opening_dest_file;
    }
}
```

And it does not have to be a one to one mapping. If you map errors one-to-one, for a depth of three functions, with three calls each, with the deeper function having 16 different possible errors, it'll map to 16 * 3 * 3 = 144 different distinct errors, which is just a maintenance hell for everyone (imagine your translators having to translate 144 error messages too… and your documentation listing and explaining them all, for a single function).

So, do not forget that functions have to **abstract** the work they're doing and also **abstract** the errors they encounter, to an understandable, locally meaningful, set of errors.

Finally, in some cases, even by keeping a whole stack trace of what happened, you won't be able to deduce the root cause of an error: Imagine a configuration reader have to look for configuration in 5 different places, it may encounter 3 "file not found", one "permission denied", and another "file not found", so it will return "Configuration not found". From here, nobody but the user can tell why it failed: Maybe the user did a typo in the first file name, and the permission denied was totally expected, or maybe the first three files are not meant to exist but the user did a chmod error on the 4th one.

In those cases, the only way to help the user debugging the issue is to provide verbose flags, like "-v" , "-vv", "-vvv", … each time adding a new level of debugging details, up to a point where the user will be able to see in the logs that the configuration had 5 places to check, checked the first one, got a file not found, and so on, and deduce where the program diverged from its intentions.

Comment: Sounds reasonable and similar to what I do right now, but it seems a lot of duplication where you can soon get over previrbial standard 50% of code just for handling errors. Keeping a whole "stacktrace" is really optional: you can always replace it with something else (like throwing separate exception constructed without caught one).

Comment: I agree, havng 50% of code just for handling errors is too much, functions have to abstract what they do and report locally meaningfull errors. I edited my answer to better reflect this.

Comment: I agree too. This is a very reasonable approach and is how, for example, POSIX libraries handle errors. The main idea here is an error indicates a violation of a contract. And the contracts should be vague but share similar criteria (i.e. if args are valid or not). This is a simple, independent approach and arguably maintains readability.

Answer (score 2):

The solution we use in one of our project is to pass special error-handling struct thru full stack of functions. This allows to get original error and message on any higher level. Using this solution your example will look like:

```
struct prj_error {
    int32_t err;
    char msg[ERR_MAX_LEN];
};

prj_error_set(struct prj_error *err, int errorno, const char *fmt, ...); /* implement yourselves */

int B(struct prj_error *err)
{
    char *file = "a/b/c/U.user";
    if (custom_read(file) != OK) {
        prj_error_set(err, errno, "Couldn't read file \"%s\". Error: %s\n",
            file, strerror(errno));
        return err->err;
    }

    if (is_empty(read_user.name)) {
        prj_error_set(err, -ENOENT, "Username in file \"%s\" is empty\n",
            file);
        return err->err;
    }
    ...
}

int A(struct prj_error *err)
{
    if (B(err) != OK) {
        if (cannot_handle_B_failing()) {
            return err.err;
        }
    }
    ...
}

main()
{
    struct prj_error err;
    ...
    if (A(&err) != OK) && (no_alternative_solution()) {
        printf("ERROR: %s (error code %d)\n", err.msg, err.err);
        wait_for_more_user_input();
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a full solution, but what I tend to do is to have each compilation unit (C file) have unique return codes. It may have a couple of externally visible functions and a bunch of static (only locally visible) functions.

Then within the C file, the return values are unique. Within the C file, if it makes sense, I also decide if I need to log something. Whatever is returned, the caller can know exactly what went wrong.

None of this is great. OTOH exceptions also have wrinkles. When I code in C++ I don't miss C's return handling, but weirdly enough, when I code in C, I can not say with a straight face I miss exceptions. They add complexity in their own way.

My programs may look like this:

<sup>some_file.c:</sup>

---

```
static int _internal_function_one_of_a_bunch(int h)
{
   // blah code, blah
   if (tragedy_strikes()) {
       return 13;
   }

   // blah more code
   return 0; // OK
}

static int _internal_function_another(int h)
{
   // blah code, blah
   if (tragedy_strikes_again()) {
       return 14;
   }

   if (knob_twitch() != SUPER_GOOD) {
       return 15;
   }

   // blah more code
   return 0; // OK
}


// publicly visible
int do_important_stuff(int a)
{
    if (flight_status() < NOT_EVEN_OK) {
        return 16;
    }

    return _internal_function_another(a) ||
           _internal_function_one_of_a_bunch(2 * a) ||
           0; // OK
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is clean way that requires a lot of boilerplate code (convert module A's A_EIO to module B's B_EIO) and prone to errors (don't check for B_EIO in return from A's functions). In addition lower level function sometimes should and sometimes should not log failure.

Comment: @dbrank0, I agree, it is full of boiler plate code and not very good. But it's the sweet-spot I bother to implement in most projects. It's not even very sweet, it just doesn't *hurt* that much... in all my travels in C land, I have not seen a generic pattern or solution to this - but maybe I should look harder. I have a hunch a global list of errors may be workable but to be practical it would almost need custom tool support - and when you are going that road, you *(at least **I**)* always may be tempted to look at other languages altogether instead.